# Using localStorage saved checkbox choice issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What am trying to archive (to do):**
Save checkbox choice in localStorage >> so users won't have to check all checkbox again and again.

**Problem:**
I am able to save choices in localStorage but the checkbox are not showing onload, the mechanism seem to also be reversed whereas checkbox checked is 
 captured unchecked etc

Am i missing something?

***Here is my code***

```js
// issue: if localStorage saves the checkbox, the input field will not display

         $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();
      });

 function save() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('activityTitleCb');
        localStorage.setItem('activityTitleCb', checkbox.checked);
      }

      function load() {
        var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activityTitleCb'));
        document.getElementById("activityTitleCb").checked = checked;
        
      }

      function wis() {
        location.reload();
        localStorage.clear()

      }

      load();
```

```css
.searchFilterBox{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chiller_cb">
              <input id="activityTitleCb" type="checkbox" class="searchFilterCb" value="activityTitleCb">
              <label for="activityTitleCb"> add my name!</label>
         
            </div>
            
            
            <br>
            
    <div class="col-sm-2 activityTitleCb searchFilterBox">

            <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="add your name" id="inputsm" type="text">
          </div>
          
          
             <br>
             
                <input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save checkbox choices" onclick="save()"/>
                <input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()"/>
```

Comment: Why would you json.parse the item you get from local storage?

Comment: @filip I need to save the "settings" in localStorage, if you have a better way, please share it?

Comment: I know, it's okay to save them. But local storage.getItem returns a Boolean already. You don't have to JSON.parse it.

Comment: @filip ah i see.. how will your solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

In function load, try to console.log(checked) to make sure the value is a boolean.
You can also try to open browser console to see what value is store on local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. You don't need to press a 'save' button because it saves it to the localStorage automatically.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyKJQq

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// issue: if localStorage saves the checkbox, the input field will not display

    $(() =>{

         $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
             if (this.checked) {
                 localStorage.setItem('activityTitleCb', true);
             }    else {

                localStorage.setItem('activityTitleCb', false);
             }
    });

 function save() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById('activityTitleCb');
        localStorage.setItem('activityTitleCb', checkbox.checked);
      }

      function load() {
        var checked = localStorage.getItem('activityTitleCb') === undefined ? false : localStorage.getItem('activityTitleCb');
        checked = (checked === 'true');
        document.getElementById("activityTitleCb").checked = checked;

      }

      function wis() {
        location.reload();
        localStorage.clear()
      }

      load();
    })
</script>
<style>
        .searchFilterBox{
          display: none;
        }</style>
<div class="chiller_cb">
              <input id="activityTitleCb" type="checkbox" class="searchFilterCb" value="activityTitleCb">
              <label for="activityTitleCb"> add my name!</label>

            </div>


            <br>

    <div class="col-sm-2 activityTitleCb searchFilterBox">

            <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="add your name" id="inputsm" type="text">
          </div>


             <br>

                <input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save checkbox choices" onclick="save()"/>
                <input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()"/>
```

Comment: this looks interesting, however the input box is not showing/hidden as per settings

Comment: dunno what you mean don't see nothing of a input box showing / hiding in your question.

Comment: when user select checkbox.. an input filed is shown.. please expand code snipet

Comment: don't see what you mean.

Comment: this div :    <div class="col-sm-2 activityTitleCb searchFilterBox">

            <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="add your name" id="inputsm" type="text">
          </div> should show/hide

Comment: When should it show and when hide? You didn't specify any of that in your question

Comment: It should show when checked... if 'checked' is saved in localStorage... then it should show, else hide